# do you need to create a separate collection/document for reading an aggregated document with firebase cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to use cloud function to produce an aggregated document containing all the data i need for the first page of my app. The aggregated document will be updated each time a document is add/updated in a Firestore collection A.
In order to do so, I have to create a separate collection B containing a single document(the aggregated doc from cloud function) which the app will fetch from when it start right? Hence, my cloud function will be updating the single document in Collection B? Am I correct in my understanding of how using cloud function to aggregate data works? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a totally valid approach. Note that you may use a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions), in the Cloud Function, if there is a risk that source data is updated by several users in parallel.

---

You don't give any detail on what is in collection A (identical docs or different docs?) and what is aggregated (numbers, headlines,...), but you should try to avoid reading all the docs from collection A each time the Cloud Function is triggered. This may generate some unnecessary extra cost. If  the first page of your app aggregates some figures, you may use some [counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters).

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response! Collection A contains different docs, and what is aggregated is : Featured Docs (docs with field Featured as true), 10 latest Docs (sort by time added). Now i am sending 2 reads each time my app loads for this, so i want to use a function to aggregate what i need into 1 document to do a 1 read only. Hence the function will add a new Doc to the list of latest Docs in the aggregated document, remove 1 Doc from the list of latest Docs in the aggregated document, add the new Doc if it is featured to its list of Featured Docs. Does this plan make sense? Thankyou

Comment: Yes it makes sense. As soon as the total cost of the solution is lower than the cost of the current situation, it makes sense. To calculate this cost you need to add the cost of the Firestore reads and write as well as the cost of the Cloud Function executions (taking the free tires, e.g. the free 2M invocations/month for Cloud Functions).